# Azure site Recovery on premise to on premise (offline initial replication)

Tags: azure

I have `2` sites. Each site has one `SCVMM` configured to do Azure Site Recovery
`ASR` is configured to replicate the `VM` form one site to another. 
Here is the issue, my `VM` size is big and i want to do the initial replication **offline** instead of over the Network and it just not allowing me saying permission issues.

Can anyone help me to find, what could be going wrong here?

ERROR MESSAGE

```
Permissions couldn't be set for one or more hosts on the initial replication folder path.
Provider error code: 31218

Provider error message:
               The VMM service couldn't provide permissions for cs\nimbl[enter image description here][1]ecs1$ on \\nimblecs1\f$. Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.. During cloud configuration, the VMM service provides permissions for Hyper-V service accounts on the import and export paths used for initial replication.
Provider error possible causes:
               The VMM service doesn't have the required privileges to modify the permissions on the import and export paths.
Provider error recommended action:
               Ensure that the VMM service account has the required privileges to perform this operation.
POSSIBLE CAUSES
Verify that the initial replication path exists and is accessible.
```

Comment: It's difficult to exactly say the cause, outside of what the error message above tells you. 

1) "The VMM service doesn't have the required privileges to modify the permissions on the import and export paths." and 
2) "Verify that the initial replication path exists and is accessible.". 

If you haven't, please check that it can write to the path it is trying to, and that it exists.

Comment: can you share any documentation around replication  policy configuration for initial offline data replication ..

Comment: I have never set up this myself, but see e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/hyper-v-vmm-disaster-recovery#set-up-a-replication-policy on how to set up replication between two vmm on-premises sites so that the first replica is offline

Comment: Tanks or your reply..

Comment: Actually, Replication Policy creation does work when I select Initial Replication Method online, The problem here is when i select the Initial replication method offline.. :(